# WebApi iActionFilter implementation. How do I read custom controller attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing custom authentication filter and using "Passive Attributes" approach described here:
http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/

DI works as expected but I can't figure out how to read custom attributes from controller itself? I would like both individual actions and whole controllers to support this functionality.

Example of controller:

```
[TokenAuth] // This attribute not "visible"
public class SupportController : ApiController
{
    private ISecurityService SecurityService { get; }

    public SupportController(ISecurityService securityService)
    {
        this.SecurityService = securityService;
    }

    [TokenAuth] // This attribute works
    [HttpGet]
    public object StartupData()
    {
        return "Startup data";
    }
}
```

This is portion of filter code where I read custom attribute:

```
public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
{
    var tokenAuthAttribute = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TokenAuthAttribute>(true).SingleOrDefault();

    // This line below exists unless attribute placed on method/action

    if (tokenAuthAttribute == null) return continuation();

    var req = actionContext.Request;
```

Is there any way to access controller's attributes?

Comment: doesn't the action descriptor give you access to the controller type via the `ControllerDescriptor` property?

Comment: Yes, I see it. Do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action descriptor should give you access to the controller type via the `ControllerDescriptor` property

```
var actionDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor;

var tokenAuthAttribute = 
    actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TokenAuthAttribute>(true).SingleOrDefault() ??
    actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<TokenAuthAttribute>(true).SingleOrDefault();

//...
```

The above checks the action descriptor first and if nothing is found then checks the controller descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete abstract class with the attribute as a generic argument. You can inherit from it, specifying your attribute, and then just override `ExecuteFilterBehavior`. This will check for the attribute on the controller and the method. You can modify it to only do one or the other.

```
public abstract class ActionFilterBehaviorBase<TAttribute> : IActionFilter where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation)
    {
        if (ControllerHasAttribute(actionContext) || ActionHasAttribute(actionContext))
        {
            return ExecuteFilterBehavior(actionContext, cancellationToken, continuation);
        }
        return continuation();
    }

    protected abstract Task<HttpResponseMessage>  ExecuteFilterBehavior(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> continuation);

    public virtual bool AllowMultiple { get; } = false;

    private bool ControllerHasAttribute(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return actionContext
                .ControllerContext.Controller.GetType()
                .GetCustomAttributes(false)
                .Any(attribute => attribute.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TAttribute)));
    }

    private bool ActionHasAttribute(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        return actionContext
            .ActionDescriptor
            .GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>()
            .Any();
    }
}
```

Some more detail [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/13/constructor-injection-webapi-actionfilters.html).